# How to allow other apps to save files to our app?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, file-sharing

I have an application that has enabled fileSharing and user can copy files into the app - I need some thing more in my application!

As you see in the photo here some applications let the user to save file to another application so how can I enable this?

I want to see my application icon here beside these apps

[image: here you can see what I want]

Answer (score 2):

You need to register that your app can open the type of document that the other app uses.

See [How do I get my application to show up in the Open in... menu](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1587/_index.html) from the Apple Developer Library Q&A.

Summary:

> To do this you need to add a document type to your app’s Info.plist for each document type that your app can open. Additionally if any of the document types are not known by iOS, you will need to provide an Uniform Type Identifier (UTI) for that document type.

Comment: I got this - i have one question: when user wants to open in can app save the file in itself or not ? and another thing is this is not explained simple please add more links here and thanks for helping

Comment: I don't understand your new question. I recommend you rephrase it, give an example of code you have tried, and post it as a separate Stack Overflow question. Similarly with the linked explanation: I think it is quite clear, so give it a go and if you get stuck, post your code and ask a new question.

Comment: I have an app that can upload files But I want when user in the another app tapped open in with files when selected my app going to my app and that file store in my app is that clear?